# Use Google to sign-in to Sharepoint 2013 through Asp.net application that uses STS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sts

I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premise that should be accessible to the users that is logged-in the asp.net Web Application  on another server.

It's so that i have asp.net Web Application that uses STS Secure token service, it uses AD and google to sign in into this application.

Is it possible to use it as authentication alternative to sign in into SharePoint ?

In other words: how to implement this scenario ?

[image]